# Is there a simple way to remove "padding" fields from numpy.dtype.descr?

Tags: python, numpy, structured-array

### Context

Since `numpy` version 1.16, if you access multiple fields of a structured array, the `dtype` of the resulting array will have the same item size as the original one, leading to extra "padding":

> The new behavior as of Numpy 1.16 leads to extra “padding” bytes at the location of unindexed fields compared to 1.15. You will need to update any code which depends on the data having a “packed” layout.

This can lead to issues, e.g. if you want to add fields to the array in question later-on:

```py
import numpy as np
import numpy.lib.recfunctions


a = np.array(
    [
        (10.0, 13.5, 1248, -2),
        (20.0, 0.0, 0, 0),
        (30.0, 0.0, 0, 0),
        (40.0, 0.0, 0, 0),
        (50.0, 0.0, 0, 999)
    ], dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8'), ('i', '<i8'), ('j', '<i8')]
)  # some array stolen from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37081693/5472354
print(a.shape, a.dtype, a.dtype.names, a.dtype.descr)
# all good so far

b = a[['x', 'i']]  # for further processing I only need certain fields
print(b.shape, b.dtype, b.dtype.names, b.dtype.descr)
# you will only notice the extra padding in the descr

# b = np.lib.recfunctions.repack_fields(b)
# workaround

# now when I add fields, this becomes an issue
c = np.empty(b.shape, dtype=b.dtype.descr + [('c', 'i4')])
c[list(b.dtype.names)] = b
c['c'] = 1

print(c.dtype.names)
print(c['f1'])
# the void fields are filled with raw data and were given proper names
# that can be accessed
```

Now a workaround would be to use [numpy.lib.recfunctions.repack_fields](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html#numpy.lib.recfunctions.repack_fields), which removes the padding, and I will use this in the future, but for my previous code, I need a fix. (Though there can be [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21413947/5472354) with `recfunctions`, as the module may not be found; as is the case for me, thus the additional `import numpy.lib.recfunctions` statement.)

### Question

This part of the code is what I used to add fields to an array (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59781119/5472354)):

```py
c = np.empty(b.shape, dtype=b.dtype.descr + [('c', 'i4')])
c[list(b.dtype.names)] = b
c['c'] = 1
```

Though (now that I know of it) using [numpy.lib.recfunctions.require_fields](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html#numpy.lib.recfunctions.require_fields) may be more appropriate to add the fields. However, I would still need a way to remove the empty fields from `b.dtype.descr`:

```py
[('x', '<f8'), ('', '|V8'), ('i', '<i8'), ('', '|V8')]
```

This is just a `list` of `tuples`, so I guess I could construct a more or less awkward way (along the lines of `descr.remove(('', '|V8'))`) to deal with this, but I was wondering if there is a better way, especially since the size of the voids depends on the number of left-out fields, e.g. from V8 to V16 if there are two in a row and so on (instead of a new void for each left-out field). So the code would become real clunky real fast.

Comment: This `padding` isn't gratuitous.  A true `view` with a subset of the fields still has to access the original data, so it has to 'know' the original dtype layout `repack` make a new array, with its own copy of the data.  Importing `recfunctions` is normal - see my recent SO answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69546473/convert-a-numpy-array-to-a-structured-array/69558330#69558330

Comment: In making new arrays, many of the `recfunctions` do edit the `dtype`, combining fields, selecting ones, etc.  So working with the the tuples in the `descr` is normal.

Comment: Except for the recent functions like `repack` and `structured_to_unstructured` which added the needs of the 1.16 changes, most of the `recfunctions` have been around for a long time.  `recarray` may have been inherited from a `numpy` predecessor, though it's largely replaced by the current `dtype` and `structured array` version.

Comment: Your first comment makes a lot of sense. Though if accessing multiple fields creats a `view`, does that mean that the convenience functions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37081693/5472354) are outdated?

Comment: Can you elaborate why importing `recfunctions` separately is normal? I don't think I understand.

Comment: Someone decided years ago that those `recarray` helper functions didn't need to be part of the main `numpy` import.  Most aren't used very often.  Even now I'm more likely to use the recent additions than the original set.  The extra import step doesn't hurt performance.  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html#record-arrays

Comment: Structured arrays seem to arise most often when people load mixed column csv files (`genfromtxt` with `dtypes=None`).  And `pandas` has probably replaced a lot of those cases. since it has more tools for dealing with mixed columns of data.

Comment: Warren's `view_fields` produces the same dtype and array as v1.16+ multifield indexing.  You can compare them yourself.  Both are `views` with that 'padding' that bothers you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [237]: a = np.array(
     ...:     [
     ...:         (10.0, 13.5, 1248, -2),
     ...:         (20.0, 0.0, 0, 0),
     ...:         (30.0, 0.0, 0, 0),
     ...:         (40.0, 0.0, 0, 0),
     ...:         (50.0, 0.0, 0, 999)
     ...:     ], dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8'), ('i', '<i8'), ('j', '<i8')]
     ...:     )
In [238]: a
Out[238]: 
array([(10., 13.5, 1248,  -2), (20.,  0. ,    0,   0),
       (30.,  0. ,    0,   0), (40.,  0. ,    0,   0),
       (50.,  0. ,    0, 999)],
      dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8'), ('i', '<i8'), ('j', '<i8')])
```

the `b` view:

```
In [240]: b = a[['x','i']]
In [241]: b
Out[241]: 
array([(10., 1248), (20.,    0), (30.,    0), (40.,    0), (50.,    0)],
      dtype={'names':['x','i'], 'formats':['<f8','<i8'], 'offsets':[0,16], 'itemsize':32})
```

the repacked copy:

```
In [243]: c = rf.repack_fields(b)
In [244]: c
Out[244]: 
array([(10., 1248), (20.,    0), (30.,    0), (40.,    0), (50.,    0)],
      dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('i', '<i8')])
In [245]: c.dtype
Out[245]: dtype([('x', '<f8'), ('i', '<i8')])
```

your overly padded attempt at adding a field:

```
In [247]: d = np.empty(b.shape, dtype=b.dtype.descr + [('c', 'i4')])
     ...: d[list(b.dtype.names)] = b
     ...: d['c'] = 1
In [248]: d
Out[248]: 
array([(10., b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', 1248, b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', 1),
       (20., b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',    0, b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', 1),
       ...],
      dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('f1', 'V8'), ('i', '<i8'), ('f3', 'V8'), ('c', '<i4')])
```

My first attempt at making a dtype that does not include the `Void` fields.  I don't know simply testing for `V` is robust enough:

```
In [253]: [des for des in b.dtype.descr if not 'V' in des[1]]
Out[253]: [('x', '<f8'), ('i', '<i8')]
```

And make a new dtype from that:

```
In [254]: d_dtype = _ + [('c','i4')]
```

All of this is normal python list and tuple manipulation. I've seen that in other `recfunctions`.  I suspect `repack_fields` does something like this.

Now we make a new array with the simpler dtype:

```
In [255]: d = np.empty(b.shape, dtype=d_dtype)
In [256]: d[list(b.dtype.names)] = b
     ...: d['c'] = 1
In [257]: d
Out[257]: 
array([(10., 1248, 1), (20.,    0, 1), (30.,    0, 1), (40.,    0, 1),
       (50.,    0, 1)], dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('i', '<i8'), ('c', '<i4')])
```

I've extracted from `repack_fields` the code that constructs a new, un-padded, dtype:

```
In [262]: def foo(a):
     ...:     fieldinfo = []
     ...:     for name in a.names:
     ...:         tup = a.fields[name]
     ...:         fmt = tup[0]
     ...:         if len(tup) == 3:
     ...:             name = (tup[2], name)
     ...:         fieldinfo.append((name, fmt))
     ...:     print(fieldinfo)
     ...:     dt = np.dtype(fieldinfo)
     ...:     return dt
     ...: 
     ...: 
In [263]: foo(b.dtype)
[('x', dtype('float64')), ('i', dtype('int64'))]
Out[263]: dtype([('x', '<f8'), ('i', '<i8')])
```

This works from `dtype.fields` rather than the `dtype.descr`.  One's a `dict` the other a list.

```
In [274]: b.dtype
Out[274]: dtype({'names':['x','i'], 'formats':['<f8','<i8'], 'offsets':[0,16], 'itemsize':32})
In [275]: b.dtype.descr
Out[275]: [('x', '<f8'), ('', '|V8'), ('i', '<i8'), ('', '|V8')]
In [276]: b.dtype.fields
Out[276]: mappingproxy({'x': (dtype('float64'), 0), 'i': (dtype('int64'), 16)})
In [277]: b.dtype.fields['x']
Out[277]: (dtype('float64'), 0)
```

another way of getting just the valid `descr` tuples from `b.dtype`:

```
In [278]: [des for des in b.dtype.descr if des[0] in b.dtype.names]
Out[278]: [('x', '<f8'), ('i', '<i8')]
```

Comment: Thanks for all the information! I really like your last approach. It's easy to understand seems robust.